# 500 Internal Server Error when mobile web app is accessed via a BlackBerry 9000 (Bold)

Tags: blackberry, mobile, mobile-website

I have a mobile web application and I'm testing the site by using various BlackBerry phones.  I've noticed that if I use a BlackBerry 9000 (Bold) and I try and login, I receive a "500 Internal Server Error", but the login works fine when I use another BlackBerry model with a different operating system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say that maybe the page is setting some additional form information via Javascript, and JS is disabled in the browser.  You may get more information by looking at the server logs which is where the 500 error is being generated.

Comment: 2010-09-08 13:50:07,384 -0400 level=ERROR class=org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/cbs].[Faces Servlet]              Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/login.faces - View /login.faces could not be restored.

Comment: Can you check if Javascript is enabled in the browser options?